Understand implementation difference between Astro dev, preview, and @astro/node standalone server
Using AstroJS: What are the differences between

dev

preview

@astro/node standalone server


What I have already, perhaps erroneously, learned:
I understand the dev server is Vite under the covers, and have learned how to configure that for https, custom port, etc.
When I build the app using:
export default defineConfig({
    output: 'server',
    adapter: node({
        mode: 'standalone',
    },
    ),

Then, I need to use environment variables to run the app on node:
PORT=4343 SERVER_KEY_PATH=certs/mykey.key SERVER_CERT_PATH=certs/mycert.crt node dist/server/entry.mjs
This leads me to believe that the standalone server is not Vite - is this correct? If so, then what "brand" of server is it?
And I have no idea what server is behind the astro preview, nor how to configure it. I did look, but all I could find were speculative answers that contradicted each other.
If I had a better understanding of the servers in these three modes, then I'd be more effective at configuration and troubleshooting.
I tried several variations and got https and custom port working for both dev and standalone servers.
astro.config.mjs:
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import node from '@astrojs/node';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    output: 'server',
    adapter: node({
        mode: 'standalone',
    },
    ),
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1', // or true
        port: 443,
    },
    vite: {
        server: {
            https: {
                key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/mykey.key'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/mycert.crt'),
            },
        }
    },
});


The node adapter is custom to Astro: source code. Not sure about the preview server, in the linked file it says about the createServer function "also used by preview entrypoint".

Thanks, provides some useful insight.
